# Замена наследования композицией

Tags: java

Есть кусок кода - класс которые считает количество вызовов метода .add(). Необходимо заменить наследование композицией.

```
public static class CountableHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {
    private int count = 0;
    public CountableHashSet(){}
    public CountableHashSet(int initCap, float loadFactor) {
        super(initCap, loadFactor);
    }
    public boolean add(E e) {
        count++;
        return super.add(e);
    }
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
        count += collection.size();
        return super.addAll(collection);
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Вот мои соображения только код не работает

```
public static class CountableHashSet<E>  {
    HashSet<E> hs = new HashSet<E>();
    private int count = 0;
    public CountableHashSet(){
    }

    public CountableHashSet(int initCap, float loadFactor) {
        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>(initCap,loadFactor);
    }
    public boolean add(E e) {
        count++;
        return hs.add(e);
    }
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
        count += collection.size();
        return hs.addAll(collection);
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Не компилируется, неправильно считает?...

Comment: В main есть еще код     `public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountableHashSet<String> s = new CountableHashSet<>();
        s.addAll(Arrays.asList("Q", "w", "df"));\
        System.out.print(s);
    }` он как раз и не работает.

Comment: Надо реализовать интерфейс и прокинуть все методы.

Comment: А как это сделать? Буду благодарен помощи.

Comment: @owlf231 а что именно не работает в методе main? не устраивает полученный вывод в консоли?

Comment: Его там просто нет. Консоль: `Main$CountableHashSet@1b6d3586
Process finished with exit code 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо переопределить метод toString() чтобы получить ожидаемый вывод.

```
public class CountableHashSet<E> {
  HashSet<E> hs = new HashSet<E>();
  private int count = 0;

  public CountableHashSet() {
  }

  public CountableHashSet(int initCap, float loadFactor) {
    hs = new HashSet<E>(initCap, loadFactor);
  }

  public boolean add(E e) {
    count++;
    return hs.add(e);
  }

  public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
    count += collection.size();
    return hs.addAll(collection);
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return count;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return hs.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CountableHashSet<String> s = new CountableHashSet<>();
    s.addAll(Arrays.asList("Q", "w", "df"));
    System.out.print(s);
  }
}
```

Так же конструктор `public CountableHashSet(int initCap, float loadFactor)` был реализован не очень хорошо, инициализировалась только локальная переменная.

Comment: А почему потребовалось переопределить toString()?

Comment: @owlf231 при наследовании реализация toString так же наследовалась от HashSet, при композиции она наследовалась от класса Object